# Reset font size of dvi file in Latex (Yap problem)

Tags: winedt, dvi

I am using WinEdt editor for LaTeX. Suddenly, the DVI file has shrinked so much in size that it is totally impossible to see it with a naked eye. Maybe that I've hit some button by mistake. It is of the following size now. Kindly help.

[image]

**P.S.** Zoom in is not working. I tried this. Posting a small code for example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin=1.2in, bmargin=1.2in, lmargin=1.3in, 
rmargin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent \Large\textbf{Response to the comments/suggestions of the referees:}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item Referee's comment:

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

And I have the following setting in View--> Options--> Display

[image]

Comment: WinEdt is just an editor, it has nothing to see with the dvi viewer. What is your distribution?

Comment: @Bernard Could you please tell me what distribution means here?

Comment: Are you under MiKTeX, TeX Live, MacTeX?

Comment: I am using MiKTex

Comment: Sorry for late response. I am using MiKTeX

Comment: Probably you should zoom from the toolbar of Yap.

Comment: @Bernard I tried using the same but it is not helping.

Comment: Could you post a small compilable code reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Bernard I provided the same. I hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: What settings do you find when you go to `View -> Options -> Display`? Does changing the rendering method, shrink factor or choosing a higher resolution printer setup help?

Comment: @siracusa I added the screenshot of the settings that you asked for. Please have a look.

Comment: I have a default shrink factor of 2 (but I haven't use yap for quite some time, so no idea if it still works).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My problem got solved. I shrank factor to 3 and now it is working. thanks